How to remove Oauth grants from websites from certain users in EntraID?
I have users signing up for all kind of apps with "Sign in with Microsoft".
I noticed I can remove the application in the user in EntraID, but it seems like users can still sign into the websites. How can prohibited certain websites for certain users in EntraID?
I've removed the access to the app in the user in EntraID. And the user can still sign in. I also waited 48h to see if there's a token issue on the website, but this is not the case.
Long story short, even if I remove the app from a user, the user can still use it.

You should decode the token on this page: https://jwt.io  It should have appid claim. Can you check if the guid is the same as your application id.
